# number_format() php remove trailing zeros

Tags: php, floating-point, numbers, decimal, number-formatting

Is there a way with `number_format()` to leave out decimal places if the number is not a float/decimal?

For example, I would like the following input/output combos:

```
50.8 => 50.8
50.23 => 50.23
50.0 => 50
50.00 => 50
50 => 50
```

Is there a way to do this with just a standard `number_format()`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add `0` to the formatted string. It will remove trailing zeros.

```
echo number_format(3.0, 1, ".", "") + 0; // 3
```

*A Better Solution:* The above solution fails to work for specific locales. So in that case, you can just type cast the number to `float` data type. Note: You might loose precision after type casting to `float`, bigger the number, more the chances of truncating the number.

```
echo (float) 3.0; // 3
```

***Ultimate Solution:*** The only safe way is to use regex:

```
echo preg_replace("/\.?0+$/", "", 3.0); // 3
echo preg_replace("/\d+\.?\d*(\.?0+)/", "", 3.0); // 3
```

**[Snippet 1 DEMO](https://ideone.com/ngBgqA)**

**[Snippet 2 DEMO](https://ideone.com/ztVTpA)**

**[Snippet 3 DEMO](https://ideone.com/ehcP2n)**

Comment: I would not recommend this solution.. For 50 it returns 5 for example.. You need to do this, if number without decimal point can occur:
`\str_contains($number, '.') ? \rtrim(\rtrim($number, '0'), '.') : $number;`

Comment: I would not recommend either! number_format() returns a string. It might work in this case but if the number is above 1000, it will cause issues. Let's say you have a number 1234.56, number_format() will return "1,234.56" and if you attempt to convert it to float, the result will be 1.0.. so no good.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use whitespace here is better solution

```
function real_num ($num, $float)
{
    if (!is_numeric($num) OR is_nan($num)  ) return 0;

    $r = number_format($num, $float, '.', ' ');

    if (false !== strpos($r, '.'))
        $r = rtrim(rtrim($r, '0'), '.');

    return $r;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$a = 50.00;

$a = round($a, 2);
```

Even though the number has 2 zeros trailing it, if you round it, it won't show the decimal places, unless they have some kind of value.

So `50.00` rounded using 2 places will be `50`, BUT `50.23` will be `50.23`.

Unless you specify at which point to round up or down, it won't change your decimal values. So just use default `round()`

Comment: This works, removes trailing decimal zeros, however it does not format the number to have comma separation.

Answer (score 0):

This function works with PHP 8 and above, or requires a polyfill for the `str_contains()` function.

```
function sanitize_float($value): string
{
    $value = (string) $value;
    if (str_contains($value, '.')) {
        $value = rtrim(rtrim((string) $value, '0'), '.');
    }

    return $value;
}
```