# those zeros will be deleted. 0.00004300 => 0.000043

Tags: php, number-formatting, zero

This code works well. Now I want to add something to it. If there are zeros after the displayed number, those zeros will be deleted. For example: 0.00004300 => 0.000043

How do you think this part can be added to the following code?

```
$num = 0.00004300;
$num_as_string = number_format($num,PHP_FLOAT_DIG,'.','');
$zeros = strspn($num_as_string, "0", 
strpos($num_as_string,".")+1);
echo number_format($num, (4+$zeros), '.', '');
```

This code works well. Now I want to add something to it. If there are zeros after the displayed number, those zeros will be deleted. For example: 0.00004300 => 0.000043

How do you think this part can be added to the following code?

```
$num = 0.00004300;
$num_as_string = number_format($num,PHP_FLOAT_DIG,'.','');
$zeros = strspn($num_as_string, "0", 
strpos($num_as_string,".")+1);
echo number_format($num, (4+$zeros), '.', '');
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php

Comment: I think that just using `sprintf('%f', $num);` can replace everything and the trimming.

Comment: Whatever pick, make sure you also test it with large non-decimal numbers such as `400` because you could end up with trailing periods, too: https://3v4l.org/B96YT

Comment: When you use `number_format()` you get a _formatted string_. When you do math you get a _number_ and trailing zeroes are meaningless to numbers. Format your string for display only, not in the middle of doing math.

Answer (score -4):

*You can just use [sprintf()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php):*

```
$num = 0.00004300;

echo sprintf('%f', $num); //0.000043
```

**Edit: better solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49890550/number-format-php-remove-trailing-zeros) using regex and covering every cases:**

```
$num = 00580.0045000;

preg_replace("/\d+\.?\d*(\.?0+)/", "", $num);

echo $num; //580.0045
```

Comment: `$num` is already a float, so there's no need for `floatval()`.

Comment: Matthias you can use [onlinephp.io](https://onlinephp.io/) to test your answer. `$num = 0.00004300; printf('%f', $num);` does the same output as your answer, so floatval does nothing.

Comment: Indeed just edited

Comment: if you found an existing answer, you are supposed to vote the question as a duplicate, not answer it

Comment: @YourCommonSense how do I do that?